# Pigeon hole at least

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

> In a team there are players between $18$ until $25$ years old. How many at least it must be to take part in one excursion, as that it will be sure that will be **at least 10 persons** same **age** and same **gender**?

What I did like this I try solve it. I believe I am wrong; if you can help me... I  take $x$ persons out of $10$ so it will give me $9$. And $9$ is the worst case so
$$\left\lceil \frac x{10} \right\rceil = \lceil9\rceil \implies \lceil x \rceil = \lceil 9\cdot10 \rceil = \lceil 90 \rceil.$$
I feel I am wrong. Can you help me?

Comment: What do your square brackets mean? Are you using them for the floor function? If so, use `$\lfloor x \rfloor$` for $\lfloor x \rfloor$.

Comment: How many pigeonholes are there?  (First, what are the pigeonholes?)

Comment: @Théophile Hi Theophile. Yes I mean this but the opposite from what you have wrote it.the bracket not down,it is up.

Comment: @saulspatz Hi saulspatz .It's a theory https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle this . Your question I didn't get it if you mean something  "How many pigeonholes are there?"

Comment: There are $2$ sexes and $8$ ages and each combination of the two gives you a relevant classification or "pigeonhole,"  so you have $16$ pigeonholes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your holes are elements of form (age, gender). There are (25 - 18 + 1) * 2 = 16 possible configurations. Now we use strong version of pigeon hole principle:

> Let q1, q2, ..., qn be positive integers. If
>
> $ q_{1}+q_{2}+\cdots +q_{n}-  n+1$ objects are distributed into n boxes, then either the first box contains at least $q_1$ objects, or the second box contains at least
> $q_2$ objects, ..., or the nth box contains at least $q_n$ objects

by this theorem you can check that distributing 145 object into 16 holes can give you at lest on hole with 10 objects. If you distrubute less then 145 there exists configuration where no hole has 10 object ie. for 144 every hole could have 9 objects.

Comment: Hi ,the answer you give it may be wrong. The answer is one of them 73 or 81
or 80
or 71 . I don't know which one of those 4 answer is the right as an  answer.

Comment: @maikl er  If there were only one gender, then 73 would be right. But in the real world, 145 is right.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I can't get  why 73 would be right.How that came from ?(If you can edit your answer so I will understand 73 I will apreciate it)

Comment: @maikl er I don't want to edit someone else's correct answer, so I'll just comment here. If there were only one gender, then the 16 in the answer would be replaced by 8, so the $144=16\times 9$ would become $72=8\times 9$, and $145=1+144$ would become $73=1+72$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass thanks a lot :D